# Enum of days in Java with Calendar

Tags: java

I would like to know if there is an existing enum containing all the week days in Java. I'm using Calendar to treat time logic but I didn't see anything like this (I could create it myself but I 'd rather use something existing). I also saw the [threeten project](http://threeten.sourceforge.net/) but it's still in alpha. Since an enum containing days of week is so trivial it's shown by sun in the enum documentation, I was thinking something may already exist. Any ideas ?

Comment: If you're looking for a sane date and time API, take a look at http://www.joda.org/joda-time/ -- if they don't have an day-of-week enum, though. Why do you need one?

Comment: @PhilippReichart I want to display tables in JSP with a column for each day.

Comment: So this is about i18n?

Comment: The back-port of java.time including its `DayOfWeek` enum is no longer alpha, and ready for production use. See the [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) project for Java 6 & 7, and further adapted for Android in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). See [`org.threeten.bp.DayOfWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/apidocs/org/threeten/bp/DayOfWeek.html).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You want [`new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/DateFormatSymbols.html#getWeekdays--).

Comment: Perfect, just what I need.

Comment: I'd add that if you need strictly US names, not your local, you should pass it into the constructor like this `new DateFormatSymbols(Locale.US).getWeekDays()`, possibly `getShortWeekDays()` for only Mon, Tue and so on.

Answer (score 3):

The troublesome old date-time classes such as `java.util.Calendar` are now legacy, supplanted by java.time classes.

## `java.time.DayOfWeek` enum

Java now includes the [`java.time.DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum.

Pass around objects of this enum rather than mere integers 1-7 to make your code more self-documenting, provide type-safety, and ensure a range of valid values.

```
invoices.printReportForDayOfWeek( DayOfWeek.MONDAY );
```

Numbering is 1-7 for Monday to Sunday, per ISO 8601 standard.

Get a localized name of the day by calling `getDisplayName`.

```
String output = DayOfWeek.MONDAY.getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;  // Or Locale.US, etc.
```

To track multiple days of the week, use an `EnumSet` (implementation of [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html)) or `EnumMap` (implementation of [`Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html)).

```
Set<DayOfWeek> weekend = EnumSet.of( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , DayOfWeek.SUNDAY ) ;
…
Boolean todayIsWeekend = weekend.contains( LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ).getDayOfWeek() );
```

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the old troublesome date-time classes such as `java.util.Date`, `.Calendar`, & `java.text.SimpleDateFormat`.

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to java.time.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations.

Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [ThreeTen-Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further adapted to [Android](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system)) in [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP).

The [ThreeTen-Extra](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as `Interval`, `YearWeek`, `YearQuarter`, and more.

Answer (score 2):

In the calendar class, there is:

```
/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Sunday.
 */
public final static int SUNDAY = 1;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Monday.
 */
public final static int MONDAY = 2;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Tuesday.
 */
public final static int TUESDAY = 3;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Wednesday.
 */
public final static int WEDNESDAY = 4;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Thursday.
 */
public final static int THURSDAY = 5;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Friday.
 */
public final static int FRIDAY = 6;

/**
 * Value of the {@link #DAY_OF_WEEK} field indicating
 * Saturday.
 */
public final static int SATURDAY = 7;
```

(source: java.util.Calendar)

Not an enum because there were none when Calendar was introduced in JDK 1.1.

Comment: I'm aware I can access each day. What I'd like is a list containing all days without to create it myself. Also, I'd like to have String values, not int.

Comment: @fxm, you should create enum by yourself if you want it, it will not take a lot of time. As said, `Calendar` class was introduced before enums came into Java

Comment: I guess I'll do so, it's just a strange something like this doesn't already exist.