# Get day string from day of week integer java

Tags: java, android, date

I need to get a day string with only a day of week integer (example : 1 = monday, 5 = friday...), I don't have any date.

I know that I can define an array of string but I think there is a better solution by using a date format. Is it possible without having a date ?

Comment: a enum sounds better

Comment: Dupe retracted: The other question is about Weekday from Date. Sorry 'bout that.

Comment: @Fildor That is indeed a duplicate, showing how to get a localized name of day-of-week.

Comment: @BasilBourque The accepted answer on this post is not correct in my case because I just have a day of week [0-6], not a full date. The correct answer, and duplicate, is this one : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329631/enum-of-days-in-java-with-calendar

Comment: @Alexr See [my Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32028420/642706) that I just now updated to `java.time.DayOfWeek`. And, no, your linked Question does not cover getting the name of day-of-week.

Comment: @AlexR. Update your Question to indicate Sunday is zero. Clarifications need to be in the Question, not the comments. And you can adjust between your numbers and the standard numbers by simply changing zero to seven and vice versa. The other six days need no adjustment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Answer found thanks to shmosel. I am using the following :

```
DateFormatSymbols.ge‌tInstance().getWeekda‌​ys()
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the [`DayOfWeek`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html) enum to get a day by its number:

```
System.out.println(DayOfWeek.of(1).toString());
```

Output:

```
MONDAY
```

Comment: this is dependent on java 1.8

Comment: Very helpful answer. With it I found DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getWeekdays() that does the job. Thanks

Comment: @AlexR. How did my answer lead you there?

Comment: Just search "android dayofweek enum" on google to find that answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18329631/enum-of-days-in-java-with-calendar because I cannot find DayOfWeek enum on Android.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply Make Array of string days and get day by Integer using indexing.......

```
String[] strDays = new String[] { "Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday","Wednesday", "Thursday","Friday", "Saturday" };

// Day_OF_WEEK starts from 1 while array index starts from 0
    System.out.println("Current day is : " + strDays[0])
```

OutPut:

```
Sunday
```

Comment: I considered this solution, but I was looking for a better one. That one requires to manage the translation.

Comment: Thursday was spelled wrong, not "Thurseday"